# Mongodb plus and minus in one query (subtract two query results)

Tags: mongodb

I have the following collection:

```
[

{
    "type": "debit",
    "amount": 10
},
{
    "type": "debit",
    "amount": 20
},
{
    "type": "credit",
    "amount": 5
},
]
```

I need to sum all documents with type debit and minus sum of credits.

how can I handle this with mongodb?

so my expected result is 25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$type",
      "field": {
        $sum: {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              "$eq": [
                "$type",
                "debit"
              ]
            },
            "then": "$amount",
            "else": {
              "$multiply": [
                "$amount",
                -1
              ]
            }
         }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "result": {
        "$sum": "$field"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/cfTixd1Oo_z